# Acessar o código fonte da Bios do computador

Tags: c, assembly

Existe alguma maneira de acessar o código fonte da Bios do meu computador? usando assembly ou c?

Comment: O código fonte posso te garantir que não tem jeito. Sem que o desenvolvedor te forneça.

Comment: Código fonte é código fonte. Só tem quem escreve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é possível acessar o código fonte e certamente as empresas não fornecerão o software nesse formato. São pouquíssimas empresas que trabalham com BIOS e cobram caro por elas, inclusive cobrando por customizações para produtos específicos.

O que talvez e com muito esforço seria possível é a engenharia reversa, olhando para o conteúdo da memória. Mas parece melhor e menos trabalhoso você observar a funcionalidade e fazer um outro código que replique/emule/simule.